# Is it possible to access and override locally scoped variables in Sass?

Tags: html, css, sass

So right now all my variables are global in scope, but this also requires unique variable names to be used so that they do not conflict.

Typically I just prepend the variable with the filename, and voila a unique variable name.

**Example 1**

_text.scss

```
$text_fontSize: 1em;
```

I don't really like this strategy, but it's what I know so far. I would prefer to wrap the variable in a class or other CSS selector so variables no longer need to be unique in each file.

**Example 2**

_text.scss

```
.sizeClass {
   $fontSize: 1em;
}
```

_paragraphs.scss

```
@use 'text' with(
   $fontSize: text.sizeClass.$fontSize;
);

p {
   font-size: $fontSize; // 1em
}
```

Pardon my ignorance as I'm relatively inexperienced with Sass. Not sure if there is a way to wrap variables in a function or object of sorts that can be called by other files, I just haven't come across examples of this.

Comment: Are you aware of [mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)?

Comment: Yes I am aware of mixins, I'm just not sure how I would go about writing a mixin to address this.

Comment: My interpretation of mixins though is that they essentially take input and output css where functions are more flexible, although I don't know if they can create things like objects. I've mostly played with a couple conditional statements and loops but haven't really used functions for anything yet. I've made a couple useful mixins that I use quite a bit, but I know I've just scratched the surface.

Comment: my sass is a little rusty, but i think you can namespace sass variables with [@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use). The docs show this example: `@use "src/corners" as c` and then accessing things like `@include c.rounded;`.

Comment: @rayhatfield yes you can do this, but the variables are still global in scope. corners.rounded is the same as c.rounded. I would want to call corners.$rounded without $rounded being global in scope. Reference: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

Comment: I'm surprised that I'd never really considered variable scope in sass, and surprised that this doesn't have a clear well-documented solution. I was thinking you could have a function that returned a map and then you could map.get specific values, but that's obviously a kludge that's going to be a pain to use. I don't think I'm going to be much help here. Good luck.

Comment: @rayhatfield I think Maps may be what I am looking for. I read up on the documentation, and while I haven't tested it yet, it's a better solution than a crazy amount of global variables *yikes*. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps. It looks like there's a way to nest Maps based on unofficial articles, but I'm not sure if it's an okay idea or a bad idea since it's not mentioned in standard documentation. Not sure if changes to Maps could break those nested Map solutions.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example of the problem you're trying to solve? I get that variable name collisions are a problem, but I don't fully see how that's going to show up in practice here. How many $textFontSize variables do you need?

Comment: @rayhatfield The most relevant use case is the use of '!Default' where I may override styles from many different style sheets. Why am I doing this, because I am designing self contained features such as a carousel or modal/light-box that I may want to use across multiple projects.

Comment: It seems like Maps is more flexible than !default but I don't yet fully understand how to use Maps effectively, so it may or may not work. I was just looking for a methodical way to manage !default variables and overrides, as having a massive list of global variables seems wrong.

Comment: This isn't an ideal place for this discussion and I get that I don't have enough information to advise you on this, but it seems like a self-contained feature shouldn't be exposing any sass variables in the first place. If it needs to be theme-able it should take that information as input rather than exposing its variables and other implementation details.